# Beginner questions about FTP clients

Tags: file-management, file-synchronization, ftp, sftp, data-transfer

I am new to programming and development but I have some beginner’s questions about FTP clients. This is not language specific in terms of my questions.

1. What are some of the best FTP clients for all experiences and levels of expertise?
2. What are some pros and cons of the particular FTP clients you like to use?
3. If you work for a company, what FTP clients do you use?

Any advice or feedback would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note that this site doesn't feature requests for product comparisions: SR is about suggesting specific software for specific needs you define. For details, see: [Is tool x versus tool y a fair question?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/69/185). Further, [list questions are no good fit for Q&A sites](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/98366/192154), and hence are [considered off-topic](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/139618/192154). SR recommends software for specific requirements you must list.

Answer (score 1):

1. Filezilla, I also like bftp http://www.bpftp.com/ and the builtin ftp in Unix.
2. Pros are the ease of use. Cons are difficulty of automating and insecurity.
3. We use scp instead, you can also look into the program scp for secure remote file transfer.